# Are duplicate submissions from different accounts flag-worthy?

Tags: discussion, flags

Tonight on SO, I've noticed a few pairs of near-identical questions being posted from different accounts.  I can't think of a good explanation for how this happens unless these questions are in a pool on some other Q/A site, with multiple users (employees?) farming them out to SO.

I find this rather annoying, even if I can't quite articulate how it differs from answering random people's questions.  Am I alone in this reaction?  I would find it most satisfying to have a flag for marking these.

**An example on the site presently at the top of the list for the [makefile] tag**:
[image: First example of post ([makefile] tag) with duplicate content.]

**Detail of the contents for the [makefile] questions**:
[image: Detail of near-identical [makefile]-tagged content.]

**Another example, also present at the moment, near the top of the search results for [crypto]**:
[image: Another example ([crypto] tag) on the site at the same time.]

Comment: Closely related on MSE: [Duo of buddies can circumvent duplicate closures under the new rule requiring an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171371)

Comment: I agree that my question is very similar to that one.  (In particular, the answer is the same: custom-flag each one).  That probably warrants closing this as a duplicate of that.

Comment: Duplicate closure doesn't work cross-site.

Comment: +1 for capturing screenshots of the offending questions, rather than just linking to them as links die after the questions get deleted.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You already have a flag for it, the custom moderator flag!

Do flag these questions. From my experience they are usually from:

- Students who attend the same college and have been given the same homework. They end up copying the complete question and posting them on Stack Overflow.
- Users who want to ask the same question again, because they feel that they've not got many views on their question, but then they find themselves q-banned, so create a new account to ask that.
- Students taking online courses, where they solve a particular problem partially and ask the students to solve the remaining. (Similarly, tech competitions, where a few users are solving it in a similar approach)
- Coworkers meeting over a chat, *Hey I'm not getting this, can you help me*, *I dunno, we can ask on Stack Overflow*, and then both return to their desks and ask the same question

All these activities are mod flag worthy. In fact, there might be some other hidden ulterior motives, which as moderators, we can discover. We do get many many similar flags. So go ahead, flag them, but be clear in your flag. Flags  like:

- duplicate < link of the other post >
- It has already been asked

etc, would mostly be declined. (The first one looks like you're requesting a duplicate vote, instead of voting to close yourself and for the second, there are nearly 15 million posts and moderators can't check all of them to see where exactly it's been asked!)

A good clear flag would be something like:

> The exact same question as this one has been posted here < link > by another user < link > already.

Which is enough for us to get to the depth of the issue and handle it.

Comment: One thing is likely untrue: If a U is q-banned, they can't simply create another account because their IP is also banned from asking.

Comment: @iBug Where did you read that from? IPs are never banned whenever there's a q-ban on one user.

Comment: Shouldn't it be [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/350567)?

Comment: No no, there are additional stuff which go on behind the scenes. It's not just, oh there's a q-banned user on an IP, let's ban everyone on that. A new account from an IP where a user has been q-banned, can ask a questions, if those questions follow a few definite set of rules. And yes, the earlier q-banned accounts do contribute to the q-ban algo.  Once a  moderator steps in and cleans that IP, then all the new accounts do get spam rammed.  (I can't really go into more details, or else, I'll be violating some mod rules)

Comment: Thanks for details. I used to think the FAQ should always cover everything.

Comment: FAQs shouldn't cover everything, else the users would find some way to circumvent the bans.

Comment: I mean, the exact criteria of mechanics are kept secret. That's fine for preventing them from being worked around. I understand. But why does the FAQ say "You can't simply create another account", which is not accurate, according to your comments?

Comment: Technically you can create a new account, but you'd be worse off than what you'd be if you hadn't. I'm not sure about why the FAQ has been written like that, though.

Comment: I guess I know why now. Great thanks for your elaboration.